# fileentry.delete succeds on Cordorva (PhoneGap) however the photo is still in the photo library

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have the following code to remove a file on a PhoneGap / Cordova Project:

```
 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(fileUrl, function(entry) {
    entry.remove(that._onFileDeleteSuccess, that._onFileDeleteErrorError);
        }, that._onFileDeleteErrorError);
```

The code executes file and the _onFileDeleteSuccess callback is fired.

However when I go to look in the Photo Library on the iPhone, the file is still there.

In addition to this, if I then capture another file, the new file name seems to be the same as the old one, and you even see the old file if you bind the URL of an img element to the newly captured path.

Any ideas?  It's as if the app thinks the file has been deleted, but the OS is not actually removing the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is just in Icenium ION on iPhone... once the app was built with provision, all seems to work as expected now.